# How to see Data passed by Ajax to PHP and what PHP does with the Data - Dropdown Menu Option

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu, html-select

I want to update my database without refreshing the page when selecting an option from my drop down menu. So I will use Ajax. 
The problem is that without refreshing the page and without seeing the PHP code running, I cannot see if there are any errors in my code in order to fix them.
Is there any way to see the data that I pass when selecting an option from my drop down to my PHP file, and see any errors the PHP file reports when processing that data?

I have tried to check the console of my browser but it doesn't display anything.

My drop down:

```
echo "<select id='vacationId' name='vacationId' style='background:lightblue'>
    <option selected='selected' value='' style='background:lightblue'></option>
    <option value='" . $vacationIdP . "' style='background:lightblue'>P</option>
    <option value='" . $vacationIdO . "' style='background:lightblue'>O</option>
    <option value='" . $vacationIdA . "' style='background:lightblue'>A</option>
    <option value='" . $vacationIdR . "' style='background:lightblue'>R</option>
</select>";
```

Ajax code to pass the option Value to a PHP file:

```
$('#vacationId').change(function(){
    var option = $('#vacationId').val();
    console.log(option);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'saveVV.php',
        data:
             {
             option:option   // Does this pass the value of the option ?
// Can I access this in my PHP file with $vacationId = $_GET['option'];
             }
    }).done(function(resp){
         if(resp == 200) {
             console.log('Success!');
         }else if(resp == 0){
             console.log('Failed..');
         }
    });
});
```

What I want is to pass the Value of the selected option to my PHP file and then do some processing to it in PHP.
And I want to see that I pass the correct info to my PHP file.
And I would like to see the PHP code running with that info and maybe displaying some errors.

Comment: use the browser debugwindow `f12`  network etc.

Comment: I wrote this AJAX wrapper a bit ago, perhaps it will help you? https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/AjaxWrapper/AjaxWrapper.php

Comment: right-click on page and select "inspect" or "inspect element" and if you are using chrome you can go to network tab and watch your ajax request.just click the request

Answer (score 0):

You can use this wrapper I wrote

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/AjaxWrapper/AjaxWrapper.php

```
class AjaxWrapper{

    /**
     * Development mode
     *
     * This is the least secure mode, but the one that
     * diplays the most information.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const ENV_DEVELOPMENT = 'development';

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const ENV_PRODUCTION = 'production';

    /**
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected static $environment;

    /**
     * 
     * @param string $env
     */
    public static function setEnviroment($env){
        if(!defined(__CLASS__.'::ENV_'.strtoupper($env))){
            throw new Exception('Unknown enviroment please use one of the '.__CLASS__.'::ENV_* constants instead.');
        }
        static::$environment = $env;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param closure $callback - a callback with your code in it
     * @param number $options - json_encode arg 2
     * @param number $depth - json_encode arg 3
     * @throws Exception
     * 
     * @example
     * 
     * 
     */
    public static function respond(Closure $callback, $options=0, $depth=32){
        $response = ['userdata' => [
              'debug' => false,
              'error' => false
        ]];
        ob_start();
         try{
             if(!is_callable($callback)){
                //I have better exception in mine, this is just more portable
                throw new Exception('Callback is not callable');
             }
             $callback($response);
         }catch(\Exception $e){
              //example 'Exception[code:401]'
             $response['error'] = get_class($e).'[code:'.$e->getCode().']';
            if(static::$environment == ENV_DEVELOPMENT){
            //prevents leaking data in production
                $response['error'] .= ' '.$e->getMessage();
                $response['error'] .= PHP_EOL.$e->getTraceAsString();
            }
         }
         $debug = '';
         for($i=0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++){
             //clear any nested output buffers
             $debug .= ob_get_clean();
         }
         if(static::environment == static::ENV_DEVELOPMENT){
             //prevents leaking data in production
              $response['debug'] = $debug;
         }
         header('Content-Type: application/json');
         echo static::jsonEncode($response, $options, $depth);
   }
   /**
    * common Json wrapper to catch json encode errors
    * 
    * @param array $response
    * @param number $options
    * @param number $depth
    * @return string
    */
   public static function jsonEncode(array $response, $options=0, $depth=32){
       $json = json_encode($response, $options, $depth);
       if(JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()){
           //debug is not passed in this case, because you cannot be sure that, that was not what caused the error.
           //Such as non-valid UTF-8 in the debug string, depth limit, etc...
           $json = json_encode(['userdata' => [
              'debug' => false,
              'error' => json_last_error_msg()
           ]],$options);
       }
       return $json;
   }
}
```

For example

```
AjaxWrapper::setEnviroment(AjaxWrapper::ENV_DEVELOPMENT);

AjaxWrapper::respond(function(&$result){
      echo "foo";
     //..other code
     $response['success'] = true;
});
```

Then when you do `console.log` it will have whatever was output within the callback as `data.debug` etc..

Hope it helps.

It uses a combination of `ob_*` output buffering and exception trapping `try/catch` to catch any output and wrap it up in an item `data.debug` or `data.error` if the environment is set correctly.

Then when you do `ajax stuff ... function(data) { console.log(data); }` it will be included.

```
   data.debug = "foo"
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dataType parameter, and the data parameter in the ajax call is a javascript object of key and value. So the key should be in single/double quotes mentioned in the code below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'saveVV.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'option':option } // In php you can access like $_GET['option']
}).done(function(resp){
     if(resp == 200) {
         console.log('Success!');
     }else if(resp == 0){
         console.log('Failed..');
     }
});
```